# Method is too complex to analyze with Try, Catch

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program which tests if a number in an array is negative and want to use try, catch if it is negative.

UPDATED:

I've changed the code around, however when an error is caught the loop stops and does not continue, how can I make the for loop move to the next int when an error is shown?

```
public class SomeClass {
    int[] table;
    int size;

    public SomeClass(int size) {
        this.size = size;
        table = new int[size];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] sizes = {5, 3, -2, 2, 6, -4};
        SomeClass testInst;
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                testInst = new SomeClass(sizes[i]);

                System.out.println("New example size " + testInst.size);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad -- I"m fundamentally confused on try/catch. But having said that, your `Println(...)` statement won't compile. Please change it to `println(...)`. Otherwise your error may be coming from somewhere else, from code not shown.

Comment: Changed it but doesn't help

Comment: Yeah, I don't see anything in that code to cause the error you're describing, and in fact, I've never seen that error in my code. I fear something else is going on in code not shown.

Comment: I've updated the code but the for loop is broken?

Comment: @user2975192 the problem did not appear in the latest version (ver 12) of `IntelliJ` so upgrading is another solution...

Comment: IntelliJ isn't throwing an exception anymore, however the loop stops after the first error is thrown, any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

This message is produced by the IntelliJ IDE when a try-catch block appears within a loop. The [original code](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23208231/revisions) is too complex for IntelliJ's data flow analysis algorithim. Upgrading to at least version 12 should eliminate this error.

Comment: Pretty poor effort on IntelliJ's part.

Answer (score 0):

You have your loop inside the try block which means if an error occurs inside the try block then it will jump to the catch block (outside of the loop).

Best way to do this would be to put the try block inside the loop. Or just not use try/catch.

Example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    if(sizes[i] < 0) {
        // Negative value
    }
    else {
        // Positive value
    }
}
```